# Can we perform any operation on data services

Tags: wso2

I need to know if i create a web service using wso2 data service ,
1 )can we create a web service sending parameters to web service and get output?

Because i heard that wso2 data servide web services doesn't take any parameters.
2)we can perform only select operations. is it true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wso2 data service  server helps you to expose your data as a service. That is if you have data in a persistent system (or if you want to store)  , you can create a dataservice and expose that to outside world..
You can do almost all possible database operations , ie: INSERT/SELECT/Update..

You can follow the product [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/WSO2+Data+Services+Server+Documentation) for further detaisl